# SOAP Response not parsed correctly c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have an Service Reference (Created by utilizing WSDL), and I can write correct messages. However when an error is returned, the information is not processed correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<RqOutboundMessage xmlns="http://www.example.com/mrl">
 <Header>
  <Version>2.0</Version>
  <CompanyID>{22354344-4234-442a-8543-d6946be94232}</CompanyID>
  <MessageID>{22354344-4234-442a-8543-d6946be94232}</MessageID>
  <MessageType>RpScheduleTask</MessageType>
  <TestMessage>0</TestMessage>
</Header>
 <RpScheduleTask>
  <ExecutionStatus>0</ExecutionStatus>
  <ErrorSignals>
   <ErrorSignal>
    <Code xmlns="">ES321</Code>
     <Location xmlns="">/RqOutboundMessage[1]/RqScheduleTask[1]/ScheduleTask[1]/Task[1]/Region[1]</Location>
     <Text xmlns="">Region should have an ExternalRegionID or InternalRegionID specified</Text>
    </ErrorSignal>
   </ErrorSignals>
  </RpScheduleTask>
 </RqOutboundMessage>
</soap:Body>
```

If I look into ErrorSignals then i'll find that there is 1 instance of this array, but all child elements are empty (NULL).

[image: All nulls]

Most likely due to the xmlns="" that is added by the other party.

Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Comment: Are You sure is bad situation? May be result is ok.

Comment: The image is the result from the XML above... as you see in the result; there clearly is an error (ES321) being generated (which is correct), however C# isn't deserializing it...

Comment: OK, check the reference.cs. Check source code. May be type of location is wrong